Reciprocals of positive integers in arithmetic progression
Question: Let $S$ be the set of the reciprocals of the first $2024$ positive integers and $T$ be the set of all subsets of $S$ whose elements form an arithmetic progression. What is the largest possible number of elements in a member of $T$?
The given answer is $\boxed{9}$, but I am unsure how to arrive at this.
I tried to let the numbers be $$\frac{a}{N}, \frac{a+2d}{N}, \frac{a+3d}{N}, \cdots, \frac{a+kd}{N}$$
Then, we would need $$N=\text{lcm}(a,a+d, a+2d, \cdots, a+kd)$$
I then tried to rewrite this as $$N=\text{lcm}(\text{lcm}(a, a+d), \text{lcm}(a+d, a+2d), \cdots, \text{lcm}(a+(k-1)d, a+kd))$$
and then use $\gcd(a,b)=\frac{ab}{\text{lcm}(a,b)}$, but I didn’t really get anywhere with that. I did incorrectly deduce that $d=1$, which doesn’t work because that gives $\frac{1}{840}, \frac{1}{420}, \frac{1}{280}, \cdots, \frac{1}{105}$, which only has $8$ terms.

If $a=4$ and $d=6$, then we get an arithmetic progression with nine terms, $N=5040$.

@indecisive: Except for a possible trick, the problem is difficult. Where did you see that the answer is 9? Do they give an example of such an A.P.?

I apologise, but there is a typo in my first comment that I didn't notice immediately. It should read:
If $a=4$ and $d=2$, then we get an arithmetic progression with nine terms, $N=5040$.

@kabenyuk: Hi, you are wrong, the common difference $d$ cannot be greater than $1$ because it should be of the form $\dfrac1a-\dfrac1b$

@Piquito
Of course it is, the difference of the arithmetic progression is $d/N=2/5040=1/2520$, but not $d$. And this is the arithmetic progression in question:
$1/1260,
1/840,
1/630,
1/504,
1/420,
1/360,
1/315,
1/280,
1/252.
$ The symbols $a,d,N$ are introduced by the author of the question and I use them.

@kabenyuk: Ah, OK, since $d$ is usually the common difference, I interpreted it that way. It seems to me that you should have published your solution. Greetings.

@Piquito I came across this problem on a site called "mathdash", and I ended up just answering with random numbers until it accepted "9" as the correct answer

@kabenyuk Do you have any idea of how to prove that 9 is maximal? I was thinking of trying a proof by contradiction, but I haven't had the chance to go through the details yet.

@Indecisive: I agree with your request to kabenyuk. It remains to find out this point.

Minor note: Do you want to start the sequence with $\frac{ a+d}{N}$? If yes, then you should get rid of the $a$ terms. If no, then you have $k+1$ terms in the AP.

Where did you encounter this question? @Indecisive

@Sahaj A contest on MathDash (a website), but I forgot which one.

I will just give some considerations, in my opinion correct, but they require careful calculations.
I use the notations introduced by the author of the question.
Here's a very brief one.

If $a=2$, $d=1$, then we get
$$
N=\operatorname{lcm}(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)=2520
$$
and the arithmetic progression  with nine terms has the form
$$
a/N,(a+d)/N,\ldots,(a+8d)/N
$$
or
$$
1/1260,1/840,1/630,1/504,1/420,1/360,1/315,1/280,1/252.
$$
Now let us prove that there are no arithmetic progressions in $S$ of $10$ terms.
Let there is such an arithmetic progression and the parameters $a$ and $d$ correspond to it. Let
$$
N=\operatorname{lcm}(a,a+d,\ldots,a+9d).
$$
We can assume that $a$ and $d$ are coprime.
In this case, the inequality
$$
N\geq a(a+d)\ldots(a+9d)/9!\tag1
$$
is true.
Now we obtain
$$
2024\geq N/a\geq(a+d)\ldots(a+9d)/9!>(a+d)^9/9!.
$$
It follows that $a+d\leq9$.
Now we will need to consider several cases ($28$ in total).

PS. Inequality $(1)$ can be made more precise and then the number of special cases can be reduced, but I don't see much point in this.
PSS. I am sure that someone can offer a more elegant solution.

Could you look at the general problem. Let $S$ be the set of $N$ first natural numbers; Determine the maximum $n$ such that $\dfrac{ab}{a+n(a-b)}$ is integer where $a,b\in S$. Are there unicity of the corresponding  $n$ quotiens?

@Piquito I didn't quite understand your question. If you want to find the maximal integer $n$ such that the number $\dfrac{ab}{a+n(a-b)}$ is integer for any $a,b\in S$, then it is $0$. If you want to find the maximal integer among those $n$ for which there exists $a,b\in S$ with integer $\dfrac{ab}{a+n(a-b)}$, then it is $N^2-1$. Perhaps there is another way to read your question.

What I have proposed is exactly what you have solved in the particular case $N=2024$ with the solution  $n=7$, the two first terms $a,b$ being $1260$ and $840$ (optionnally $252$ and $280$ if you take the common difference of the A.P. negative). It is equivalent wihtout mention any A.P.

@Piquito I finally understood your question. For a given $N$ we need to find the maximal among those integers $n$ for which there exist such $a, b\in S$ that all numbers of the form $\dfrac{ab}{a+k(a-b)}$, $k=1,\ldots,n$, are integers. Right? Honestly I think the task seems more difficult in this formulation.

You can cut down on cases by using $(a+d)\dots(a+9d)$ instead, as then you find (for $d=3$) $1 \cdot 4 \cdot \dots \cdot 28$ (for $d=2$) $3 \cdot 5 \cdot \dots \cdot 21$ (for $d=1$) $4 \cdot  5 \cdot \dots \cdot \ 13$ all exceed the bound, leaving you with just $4$ more cases. Almost doable by hand.

Preamble: This is NOT a complete solution. The gap in my proof occurs at "(I can't prove this rigorously)" onwards, where I'm providing my best guess.
If my claim is correct, then as the sequence is not in OEIS, that makes me doubtful that there has been significant progress made on this general problem.

Let $a_i$ be the minimum value of the upper bound that will give us $i$ terms of an AP of the desired form. We can calculate that $$a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, a_3 = 6, a_4 = 12, a_5 = 30, a_6 = 60, a_7 = 420, a_8 = 840, a_9 = 1260, \ldots$$
At initial glance, one might think that we have $a_i = lcm(1 , 2, \ldots i)$. However, that is not the case with $a_5 = 30$ (with AP $\frac{1}{30}, \frac{1}{20}, \frac{1}{15}, \frac{1}{12}, \frac{1}{10}$), where we append $\frac{1}{60}$ to get the 6-term AP.
Similarly, that's not the case with $a_9 = 1260$ (see kabenyuk's set), where we append $ \frac{1}{2520}$ to get the 10-term AP.
What is unique about the counter examples 5 and 9? Out of the first 10 integers, the non prime-powers are 6 and 10, and so 5 and 9 are both 2 less than the next largest prime power. You will see how this is used in a moment.
Claim: The correct formula is $a_n =  \frac{ lcm(1, 2, \ldots, m) }{m - n +1 } $, where $m+1$ is the smallest prime power $>n$.
Corollary: As $a_{10} = 2520 > 2024> 1260 = a_9$,  hence the answer to the problem is 9.
Furthermore, we have a unique AP (requires some work, but should be obvious by trial-and-error).

Attempt at proving the claim
(Sorry that I switched the AP from having $n$ terms to having $k$ terms.)
Let the sequence of integers be $n_1, n_2, \ldots n_k$ in increasing order.
Show that $ n_I = \frac{ n_1 n_2 } { (I-1) n_1 - (I-2) n_2 } $. The pattern can be observed by calculating $n_3, n_4$, and proved by induction.
Note that from $n_k > 0 $, we get an upper bound $k < \frac{ 2n_2 - n_1 } { n_2 - n_1 } $ based on the first 2 starting terms. This can also be derived directly from $ \frac{1}{n_k} = \frac{1}{n_1} + (k-1) (\frac{1}{n_2 } - \frac{1}{n_1} ) > 0 $.
Let $ d = \gcd (n_1, n_2)$, with $ n_1 = da, n_2 = db, \gcd(a, b) =1, a < b$.
From the denominator of $n_I$, we have $(2b-a) + I (a-b) \mid dab$ which gives us a lower bound for $dab$ in terms of $a, b, k$.
(I can't prove this rigorously)
To get that $(2b-a) + I (a-b) \mid dab$, we'd likely want

$a-b = - 1$,

Note that setting $a-b = - 2$ likely increases $lcm( (2b-a) + I (a-b) ) $. However, this need not be the case.


$2b - a \approx k$

To minimize $n_k = \frac{ dab } { 2b-a + k(a-b) }$, we'd likely want:

$ dab = lcm(1, 2, \ldots k)$.

We have $ dab \geq  lcm( (2b-a) + I (a-b) )  \geq lcm(1, 2, \ldots k)$.
We likely have $dab \geq  lcm( (2b-a) + I (a-b) ) \geq lcm ( 1 - I (a-b) )$


Once $a-b$ is fixed, we want $2b-a =  b - (a-b) = 2a - 2(a-b) $ to be large.

These then yield the solution set

$ a = m$, $b = m-1$
$d = \frac{lcm(1, 2, \ldots, m)} { m(m-1) } $,
$m+1$ is the smallest prime power $>k$.

Note that this choice of $m$ allows us to keep the numerator of $d$ and increase the denominator, thereby decreasing $d$ and allowing us to increase $ab$ and hence $b$.



With this solution set, we get $ n_k = \frac{ n_1 n_2 } { (k-1) n_1 - (k-2) n_2 } = \frac{ dab } { m-k + 1 }  =  \frac{ lcm(1, 2, \ldots, m) }{m - k +1 }$ as desired.
Also, the AP can be obtained explicitly, and has the nice form:  $n_i = \frac{lcm(1, 2, \ldots, m) } {m-i + 1 }. $
Reasons why the guessed solution set could be faulty

We use a slightly larger value of $dab$ while significantly increasing $ (2b-a) + k(a-b)$, which seems very unlikely.
We use $a- b \neq - 1$ which reduces $ lcm ( (2b-a) + I(a-b))$. This is possible for large enough $a$.

EG Setting $b $ such that $ a-b \mid a$ will allow us to reduce the LCM. We could get around this by forcing $ \gcd(a, b) = 1$.
Even with that added assumption, for large enough $a$, it's possible for $lcm ( a + 2I ) < lcm ( a + I )$, like if the latter has many primes that are skipped over.



